# what is the idiomatic way to slice a map in Clojure?

Tags: dictionary, clojure, standard-library

For lists and vectors, we can slice the sequence and take any portion we want.
How to do similar operations to map objects ?

For example, I have a list of map object,

```
(def plays [
        {:name "Burial",     :plays 979,  :loved 9}
        {:name "Eno",        :plays 2333, :loved 15}
        {:name "Bill",       :plays 979,  :loved 9}
        {:name "Magma",      :plays 2665, :loved 31}])
```

For each map, I want to slice off plays column, and add rate column with default value, what is the idiomatic way to do this ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`assoc` and `dissoc`  are your friends in this case:

```
(map #(-> % (dissoc :plays) 
            (assoc :rate 10)) plays)
```

Answer (score 15):

Depending on your use-case, you might also find `select-keys` useful in addition to `assoc` and `dissoc`:

> ```
> clojure.core/select-keys
> ([map keyseq])
>   Returns a map containing only those entries in map whose key is in keys
> ```

```
(select-keys {:name "Eno" :plays 2333 :loved 15} [:name :loved])
;; => {:name "Eno" :loved 15}
```